# Не могу подключить БД MySQL к Visual Studio 2019 16.11.21

Tags: mysql, база-данных, visual-studio-2019

При попытки открыть список БД появляется ошибка "Unable to retrieve the list of databases".
[image: Ошибка]
Проверка подключения проходит без ошибок.

[image: Проверка подключения]
[image: Установленные программы]

Пробовал переустанавливать Visual Studio и всё ПО связанное с MySQL, но это не помогло.
Все методы из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664418/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-to-visual-studio тоже не помогли.

---

Ошибка
[image: Ошибка]

Вот база и путь к ней
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка Data

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте Database Name 1. The first important parameter is the database name 2. The next important aspect is the username and password which needs to be used to establish a connection to the database - https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-access-database.html

Comment: При попытки подключения через объект SqlConnection пишет, что не удалось найти указанный файл. Папка Data по пути C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 не отрывается и весит 0 байт.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос(в конце) что за ошибку выдаёт и строку connection добавьте. Ещё, вы базу-то создали перед тем как её открыть?

Comment: connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydb;UID=root;PASSWORD=1234;"

Comment: Ошибка осталась прежней.

Comment: пробуйте со строкой подключения: 127.0.0.1 виесто localhost.  - https://betacode.net/10517/work-with-mysql-database-in-csharp

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Смог подключиться с помощью объекта MySqlConnection

```csharp
   using MySqlConnector;
    
    
    namespace db_1
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;       
            connectionString = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=mydb;port=3306;User id=root;PASSWORD=1234";
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
        }

    }
```